# How to achieve google calendar EditText look

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-styles

I would like to make my EditText fields look like in Google Calendar app:

[image: Screenshoot google calendar app]

Does anyone have some snippet to get that look with minimal cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same `EditText` in one of my projects.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_new"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Enter title"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is the `xml` code for "add location" part:

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:alpha="0.54"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_place_dark"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_gravity="fill|start"
                app:layout_row="8" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/location_new"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                app:layout_gravity="fill|start"
                app:layout_row="8"
                android:hint="Add Location"
                />
```

As I mentioned in comment the key points are in background color and text color and padding.

The `row` and `column` and other attributes here are for using `GridLayout`. You can achieve the same design by using `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have similar snippet for the fields below (such as Add location). I mean only the style, not the functionality after click. Most of my fields will be EditText, but I want that look. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RMK Actually there is no magic part in this code. The key points are setting background color to transparent and changing text color and hint color. Also you should change the default padding. I update my answer and include add location part.